# Enquadrar uma imagem dentro de outra

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tendo um pouco de dificuldade em implementar a seguinte situação:

1. Ler uma pasta com várias imagens;
2. Tenho que ler as imagens e redimensionar cada uma para a resolução 720x185;

Eu consegui realizar o redimensionamento da imagem como o código a seguir.

```py
from PIL import Image
    
path = 'informe o caminho da imagem'
    
image = Image.open(r"" + path + "")
image = image.resize((720,185))
image.save(path)
```

Contudo, eu tenho imagens quadradas onde elas ficam distorcidas, então o que eu precisava fazer era o seguinte:

1. Gerar uma imagem em branco com a resolução de 720x185;
2. Inserir a imagem lida no centro da imagem nova criada, respeitando apenas a altura. Com isso, acredito que não ficaria distorcida;

Como posso realizar essa tarefa?

Answer (score 1):

Dimensionar com valores fixos não vai funcionar mesmo. Pra manter a proporção você tem que fazer um pequeno cálculo.

Primeiro tem que pegar a largura desejada e dividir pela largura da imagem original, assim vai gerar valor que será usado como multiplicador. Na sequência, esse multiplicador vai calcular a sua nova altura.

Por exemplo:

```
from PIL import Image
    
path = 'informe o caminho da imagem'
image = Image.open(r"" + path + "")

new_width = 720
multiplier = new_width / image.width
new_height = image.height * multiplier
    
image = image.resize((new_width, new_height))
image.save(path)
```

Comment: Interessante sua idéia mas meu principal problema é que a altura precisa ser de 185 ou seja preciso ter a largura de 720 e altura de 185 em alguns casos nas imagens que verifiquei elas ficam com o 720 de largura mas com uma altura superior a 185 alguma idéia de como reverter essa situação?